# How to export and import ST_GEOMETRY from Oracle environment to another Oracle environment?

Tags: export, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I have a geographic layer stored in an Oracle Geodatabase with ST_GEOMETRY type.

I'd like to export that layer and its data into a SQL INSERT format in order to import it into another Oracle database which is in another server machine.

After the export I get lines like this:

`Insert into myTable(OBJECTID,NAME,SHAPE) values ('2989','MyName','SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(8,1120,672587.528700002,6824864.9106,676521.2799,6829005.2801,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8002536.39765853,16898.2791219904,3,'oracle.sql.BLOB@5e105008'));`

I don't know how to deal with the BLOB type. I suppose `oracle.sql.BLOB@5e105008`references a memory address where some data is stored. How can I export that belob and import it in the new Oracle DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Pump Export**

> is a utility
>   for unloading data and metadata into a set of operating system files
>   called a dump file set. The dump file set can be imported only by the
>   Data Pump Import utility. The dump file set can be imported on the
>   same system or it can be moved to another system and loaded there.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm

Comment: Should I prefer sdeexport/sdeimport to datapump?

Comment: sdeexport is slower.